# Replication a view from SQL Server (on-prem) to Azure SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

I have an on-premise SQL Server and I want to access the data from Azure WEB APP so the best solution found is creating a view on the on-premise server and setup transnational replication only on that view to Azure SQL.

I've set up the replication and I keep getting this error:

> Reference to database and/or server name in '..' is not supported in this version of SQL Server

I think the problem is that the view is replicated as a command (CREATE VIEW ...) and not as raw data.

The SQL Server is the publisher, and the there is no way to expose any internal network ports.

Is there a way to replicate the view as raw data and not indexed?

Comment: The error is because your view references databases like this in it: `FROM Database.dbo.Table`. Remove the database part. Hopefully it is only referencing the current database. If not, it's not going to work. How much data is in the view and how quickly does this data need to be visible to your app?

Comment: As mentioned below, replicating the view won't work. You need to replicate the base tables and remove the database names from your view definition

Answer (score 0):

Transnational Replication replicates views, but just the view definition.  You have to either replicate the base tables, or make the view an [Indexed View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-ver15) and Replicate the Indexed View as a Table.  In the docs for [sp_addarticle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addarticle-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) this is called `@type = 'indexed view logbased'`.  Or there's lots of articles on the internet about this.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by creating a new SSIS job that handles that merge and runs once in a hour.
I dont need the data live in my webapp so this worked for me.